# Conflict handling in DomainContext

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql, ria, conflict

I have a Linq-to-SQL RIA service and a silverlight client. When 2 people edit the same entity I receive an EntityConflict in the OnSubmitCompleted when calling SubmitChanges. 
Now I want to react to it without annoying the user too much, I only want to show him a message box and let him know that the data has been modified and that his changes will be overridden with the server values.

```
MyDomainContext.SubmitChanges(this.OnSubmitCompleted, invokeAfterSubmit);

private void OnSubmitCompleted(SubmitOperation so)
{
 if (so.HasError)
 {
 if (so.EntitiesInError.Any(entity => entity.EntityConflict != null))
  {
  MessageBox.Show("Data has changed, entities will be reloaded....","Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);

  // cache the entities, because the AcceptChanges() will clear them
  var errorEntities = so.EntitiesInError.ToList();

  // overwrite the local changes with the ones from the stoe
  ((IChangeTracking)Context.EntityContainer).AcceptChanges();

  // reload the data
  -> here comes the dirty code from below                  


  // mark as handled as in "The User has been informed that all his stuff has been reverted"
  so.MarkErrorAsHandled();
  }
 }
```

I have no idea how to reload the data for this specific entity. I would not even mind reloading that whole data again.

At the moment I am doing this, and I feel very dirty :)

```
foreach (Entity entity in errorEntities)
  {
   var methodInfo = (from method in Context.GetType().GetMethods()
                     where method.Name.Contains("Query")
                     where method.Name.Contains(entity.GetType().Name)
                                         select method);

   foreach (var info in methodInfo)
     {
     // get the query from the Context to reload the entity
      var result = (EntityQuery) info.Invoke(Context, null);

      // load the entities
       Context.Load(result, LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, null, null);
     }

   }
```

This works, but I am sure there are better ways to resolve conflicts. (Merging would of course be great!)

Please let me know of better ways to handle this scenario :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem with the conflicts can be solved on the server. The domain service is a partial class where you can override the method `ResolveConflicts`.

Example:

```
protected override bool ResolveConflicts(ChangeConflictCollection conflicts)
{
    bool resolveChangeSetSuccess = true;

    foreach (ObjectChangeConflict objectChangeConflict in conflicts)
    {
        foreach (MemberChangeConflict memberChangeConflict in objectChangeConflict.MemberConflicts)
        {
            if (memberChangeConflict.Member.Name == "Name of DB field")
            {
                memberChangeConflict.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues);
            }
            else
            {
                memberChangeConflict.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepChanges);
            }
        }

        resolveChangeSetSuccess = resolveChangeSetSuccess && objectChangeConflict.IsResolved;
    }

    if (resolveChangeSetSuccess)
    {
        this.DataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }

    return resolveChangeSetSuccess;
}
```